# ¿Cómo generar espacios en una tabla?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net

Mi problema es el siguiente:

¿Cómo puedo generar espacios entre las filas de mi tabla en ASP.NET?

Probé con varias cosas, pero no funcionaron.

Este es mi código:

```
<table align="center">

        <tr>
            <td width="%50">
                <asp:Label ID="lblTransaccion" runat="server" Text="Se le ha asignado un numero a la transaccion a cargar: "></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td width="%50">                    
                <asp:Label ID="lblTransaccionValor" runat="server" Text=" "></asp:Label>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
             <td width="%50" align="left">
                  <asp:Label ID="lblCodigo" runat="server" Text="Ingrese codigo de cuenta a cargar: "></asp:Label> 
             </td>
            <td width="%50" align="right">                   
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCodigo" runat="server" Width="300"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

             <td width="%50">
                 <asp:Label ID="lblImporte" runat="server" Text="Ingrese importe a cargar:  "></asp:Label>
             </td>
            <td width="%50" align="right">                
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtImporte" runat="server" Width="300"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es colocar directamente el código HTML para espacio:

```
&nbsp;
```

Ejemplo: para agregar espacios a este Label:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblImporte" runat="server" Text="Ingrese importe a cargar:  " />
```

Puedes cambiarlo así *(le he agregado dos espacios - usando `&nbsp;`)*:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblImporte" runat="server" Text="Ingrese importe a cargar:&nbsp;&nbsp;" />
```

> **NOTA:** Aunque considero que esta no es una buena práctica; puede ser que tu problema real sea aplicar estilos para la organización de
>   los datos de tu tabla. Si es así, debes publicar una nueva pregunta
>   con lo que hayas intentado.

Fuente: [caracteres y símbolos ASCII - HTML](https://ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm).